# Update Data parameter of a localized script in Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on a child theme, In `my-page-template.php` I have :

```
$id_curr= 5; //calculated value through code
wp_localize_script('my_js', 'ajaxload', array('post_id' => $id_curr));
```

In `my_js.js` I have an AJAX call :

```
$.ajax({
   //...
   type: 'post',
   data: {
      action: 'ajax_load',
      post_id: ajaxload.post_id
   }
})
```

---

Now in `functions.php`, I want to edit/update `ajaxload.post_id` according to a new result. Is there a way to do that? If I try re-calling `wp_localize_script()` with the same `$name` as shown below, will this work?

```
$id_new= 8; //new calculated value
wp_localize_script('my_js', 'ajaxload', array('post_id' => $id_new));
```

Comment: How would you decide the value of `$id_new`?

Comment: @Octopi In the function that I call via AJAX (located in functions.php), I make a `$_POST`, `$id_new` is `ajaxload.post_id + $n`, `$n` is how many time the condition of a while loop was true.

Comment: Can yoiu post the function please?

Comment: The question that I asked is actually a very simplified version of my issue, the function is very long, I tried to simplify it but its still too long and it needs to largely extend both `my-page-template.php` and `my_js.js` parts. What I'm trying to do, is sending back a response with data from the PHP handler after a successful AJAX request.

Comment: I think your approach may be wrong here. localize script is really meant to store constants. I think you would be better off storing this value in an html data attribute and updating it as needed.

Comment: @Chris That is the alternative that I'm actually using, but I'm still curious to know if there is another way to do that with `wp_localize_script` or other Wordpress function.

Comment: You could try editing the global `$wp_scripts` which holds the data for the localization information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deep research, I venture to answer my question.

Wordpress have the function `wp_send_json()` that allows to send a response back to an AJAX request. This function can update `ajaxload.post_id`.

In `functions.php` :

```
$return = array('post_id' => $id_new);
wp_send_json($return);
```

In `my_js.js` :

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   data: {
      action: 'ajax_load',
      post_id: ajaxload.post_id
   },
   success:function(data) {
      var result = $.parseJSON(data);
      ajaxload.post_id = result.post_id;
   }
});
```

Comment: What if one is returning a wordpress loop, in ajax, and in addition requires an update to a localized data parameter?

Answer (score -1):

create an array with IDs.

```
$ids = array( 5, 8 );
foreach ( $ids as $id ) {
    wp_localize_script('my_js', 'ajaxload', array('post_id' => $id));
}
```

Comment: I need to change the value of the variable since its processed several times in different files. Even if it's an array, I'll need to dynamically change their values.